# How to exclude org elements from jacoco coverage report?

Tags: android-source, jacoco

I'm working on enable java code coverage for AOSP. I added jacoco option in Android.bp ,make the module/test with coverage option:

```
EMMA_INSTRUMENT=true EMMA_INSTRUMENT_FRAMEWORK=false EMMA_INSTRUMENT_STATIC=true ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK=false SKIP_BOOT_JARS_CHECK=true -f build/core/main.mk MODULES-IN-external-jacoco
```

But my coverage.html report includes lots of org elements. How to exclude them? I only want to get the module's coverage.

The org elements are like: org.jacoco.core.tools

[See screenshot of these elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Jbf.png)

Created with JaCoCo 0.7.10.201704181138.android